# ASUS UX501 - Ubuntu - touchpad doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, asus

On my brand new UX501 the touchpad works kind of ok (precision isn't great) but what does not work at all is the 2-fingers scrolling. I've been searching on Internet *a lot* but haven't find any solution so far.
Also when I left-click some text in order to copy it, then I release the lef button, the pointer moves randomly, so that it's impossible to copy the right text.
In general, the touchpad is lamost inusable (on Windows it works perfectly).
This is supposed to be the touchpad model ("USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller"):

```
$ sudo libinput-list-devices  | grep -i touch -5
Device:           USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller
Kernel:           /dev/input/event10
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             341.25x195.00mm
Capabilities:     touch
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
```

Is it just me? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also own Asus UX501 and I also faced this problem for a long time. Laptop is awesome but without touchpad multi-touch functionality, you can not make full use of it on Ubuntu.

If you on kernel version less than 4.10, you can try using [this](https://github.com/vlasenko/hid-asus-dkms) kernel module.

As per [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_Pro_UX501), I think this module got added in core kernel 4.10, so if you upgrade your kernel to 4.10+ it should work by default.

Just to confirm, I am currently using 4.13.11 version of kernel and multi-touch has started working for me on my UX501 laptop by default.

Comment: Not sure when it got fixed, but I no longer have this problem (Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.10.0-38)

Comment: Yes, it got fixed in kernel ver 4.10. As now you are running on 4.10.0.38, so its there in your kernel.